# Apply function over relative rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, apply

It seems that applying functions to data frames is typically wrt series (e.g df.apply(my_fun)) and so such functions index 'one row at a time'. My question is if one can get more flexibility in the following sense: for a data frame df, write a function my_fun(row) such that we can point to **rows above or below** the row.

For example, start with the following:

```
def row_conditional(df, groupcol, appcol1, appcol2, newcol, sortcol, shift):
    """Input: df (dataframe): input data frame
              groupcol, appcol1, appcol2, sortcol (str): column names in df
              shift (int): integer to point to a row above or below current row
       Output: df with a newcol appended based on conditions
    """
    df[newcol] = ''  # fill new col with blank str
    list_results = []
    members = set(df[groupcol])
  for m in members:
     df_m = df[df[groupcol]==m].sort(sortcol, ascending=True)
     df_m = df_m.reset_index(drop=True)
     numrows_m = df_m.shape[0]
     for r in xrange(numrows_m):
     # CONDITIONS, based on rows above or below
         if (df_m.loc[r + shift, appcol1]>0) and (df_m.loc[r - shfit, appcol2]=='False'):
                df_m.loc[r, newcol] = 'old'
            else:
                 df_m.loc[r, newcol] = 'new' 
    list_results.append(df_m)
return pd.concat(list_results).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Then, I'd like to be able to re-write the above as:

```
def new_row_conditional(row, shift):
    """apply above conditions to row relative to row[shift, appcol1] and row[shift, appcol2]
    """
 return new value at df.loc[row, newcol]
```

and finally execute:

```
df.apply(new_row_conditional)
```

Thoughts/Solutions with 'map' or 'transform' are also very welcome.

From an OO-approach, I might imagine a row of df to be treated as an object that has attributes i) a pointer to all rows above it and ii) a pointer to all rows below it. Then referencing row.above and row.below in order to assign the new value at df.loc[row, newcol]

Comment: of course, one alternative is writing a for loop employing df.loc[i, col] and df.loc[i-1, col], but I generally find apply or transform with functions computationally faster

Comment: `rolling_apply()` can handle simple cases.  `iterrows` ought to be able to handle just about anything though.  It's not fast but I don't think any general solution here is going to be either.

Comment: Have you looked at using the `shift` method to shift rows up or down?  This works well if you are trying to make use of rows at particular relative positions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can always look into the enclosing execution frame:

```
import pandas
dataf = pandas.DataFrame({'a':(1,2,3), 'b':(4,5,6)})

import sys
def foo(roworcol):
    # current index along the axis
    axis_i = sys._getframe(1).f_locals['i']
    # data frame the function is applied to
    dataf = sys._getframe(1).f_locals['self']
    axis = sys._getframe(1).f_locals['axis']
    # number of elements along the chosen axis
    n = dataf.shape[(1,0)[axis]]
    #  print where we are
    print('index: %i - %i items before, %i items after' % (axis_i,
                                                           axis_i,
                                                           n-axis_i-1))
```

Within the function function `foo` there is:

- `roworcol` the current element out of the iteration
- `axis` the chosen axis
- `axis_i` the index of along the chosen axis
- `dataf` the data frame

This is all needed to point before and after in the data frame.

```
>>> dataf.apply(foo, axis=1)
index: 0 - 0 items before, 2 items after
index: 1 - 1 items before, 1 items after
index: 2 - 2 items before, 0 items after
```

A complete implementation of the specific example you added in the comments would then be:

```
import pandas
import sys
df = pandas.DataFrame({'a':(1,2,3,4), 'b':(5,6,7,8)})

def bar(row, k):
    axis_i = sys._getframe(2).f_locals['i']
    # data frame the function is applied to
    dataf = sys._getframe(2).f_locals['self']
    axis = sys._getframe(2).f_locals['axis']
    # number of elements along the chosen axis
    n = dataf.shape[(1,0)[axis]]
    if axis_i == 0 or axis_i == (n-1):
        res = 0
    else:
        res = dataf['a'][axis_i - k] + dataf['b'][axis_i + k]
    return res
```

You'll note that whenever additional arguments are present in the signature of the function mapped we need jump 2 frames up.

```
>>> df.apply(bar, args=(1,), axis=1)
0     0
1     8
2    10
3     0
dtype: int64
```

You'll also note that the specific example you have provided can be solved by other, and possibly simpler, means. The solution above is very general in the sense that it is letting you use `map` while jailbreaking from the row being mapped but it may also violate assumption about what `map` is doing and, for example. deprive you from the opportunity to parallelize easily by assuming independent computation on the rows.

Comment: Thanks. To bow-tie your answer: Suppose df = pd.DataFrame({'a':(1,2,3,4), 'b':(5,6,7,8)}) and let k > 0 be a positive number. 

How could we define a method bar(row, k) so that it returns a[index + k] + b[index - k] if the two summands exist relative to the current 'index' and 0 otherwise? For k = 1, we should get, for df['new']  = df.apply(bar, args=(k,), axis=1), the following result:

list(df['new']) = [0, 8, 10, 0]

Comment: Thank you! You've supplied a well-explained answer to my general question. Your comments also lead to further exploration

Answer (score 2):

Create duplicate data frames that are index shifted, and loop over their rows in parallel.

```
df_pre = df.copy()
df_pre.index -= 1
result = [fun(x1, x2) for x1, x2 in zip(df_pre.iterrows(), df.iterrows()]
```

This assumes you actually want everything from that row. You can of course do direct operations for example

```
result = df_pre['col'] - df['col']
```

Also, there are some standard processing functions built in like `diff`, `shift`, `cumsum`, `cumprod` that do operate on adjacent rows, although the scope is limited.